# ElasticSearch Query Search with Highlight C# Nest

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I'm tying to get the highlight results back for the following query search. Need some help to point me in the correct direction.\

Using Nest 5.4.0 and ElasticSearch server 5.5.0

```
var results = client.Search<Customer>(s => s
              .Query(q => q.QueryString(qs=>qs.Query(searchTerm)))
              .Highlight(h=>
                    h.Fields(f=>
                       f.Field("*")
                       .HighlightQuery(q => 
                          q.QueryString(qs => s.Query(searchTerm))))
));
```

Here is the Request JSON

```
{
  "highlight": {
   "fields": {
    "*": {
      "highlight_query": {
      "query_string": {
        "query": "a"
      }
    }
  }
}
  },
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "a"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: would you be able to post the actual http request

Comment: I added the request JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of do the query_string query I change it to a multi_match

```
{
   "from": 0,
   "size": 10,
   "query": {
   "multi_match" : {
         "query":    "Troy", 
         "fields": [ 
               "customer_num^2", 
               "full_name^3", 
               "invoice_numbers", 
               "ticket_number", 
               "transaction_number" ]                        
                }
            },
            "highlight" : {
                    "fields" : [
                    {"customer_num":{}}, 
                    {"full_name":{}},                         
                    {"invoice_numbers":{}}, 
                    {"ticket_number":{}}, 
                    {"transaction_number":{}}
                ]
            }
            }  
            }
           }
```

Comment: How to write this in NEST query?